# RWD and Default package magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

In magento I have two built in packages RWD and Default. I've noticed that RWD has a folder called scss and the Default package doesn't.
Whats the difference in the two packages ?
I found a video that looks at the Default package which copies the css and images into another theme directory and edits the files. Is this the correct way for the default package?

Answer (score 0):

By Default Magento Provide these package

**RWD** Means - Responsive Web Design

**Default** Means - it's not a responsive if you want you can customize

**scss** it's on the css method you can declare your css like a variable and then use any where in your theme

```
$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

body {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;
}
```

for more you can refer this http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_dev-guide.html

Comment: I found a video that looks at the Default package which copies the css and images into another theme directory and edits the files. Is this the correct way for the Default package?

Comment: they copied rwd-> default into some custom name right

Comment: in rwd->default it's like a core file of rwd if you want to override you create new theme then copy that and then edit your custom theme. Don't edit custom theme

Comment: Sorry, i'm referring to the Default package and not RWD package
See https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-theming/706-video-magento-theming
Is this video okay to follow?

Comment: if you want to by default responsive website or you have to customize the responsive

Comment: I don't want responsive (RWD), the css is too difficult to edit as it uses compilation of CSS. 
Hence simpler option of the Default package as demo video .. is the video correct for the Default package?

Comment: if don't want to responsive then you create a folder called your theme name and then copy all default folder into your theme folder

Comment: ok understood. Finally, why has RWD package used compiled css and Default package hasn't?

Comment: because of Responsive web design so that it have but default does not support responsive so that